# Obj-C Alternative storyboard for landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, orientation

Quick question. Is this possible to create storyboard to landscape orientation? I have to change some positions of elements in views and I can't use auto-layout to deal with it. Of course I can write it in code, but I think it's unnecessary. I'm quite new in iOS developer, but I was working as Android developer. There we could create different folders for every instance. I think it should look like this:

> Main.storyboard
>
> Main_iPad.storyboard
>
> Main_landscape.storyboard
>
> Main_landscape_iPad.storyboard

Of course creating different files is not a problem. Problem is: how to link it properly in my code/plist/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: Don't create a separate nib/storyboard for landscape version of the same view unless your layout is completely different. Auto-Layout should handle layout changes upon orientation change.

Assuming you have good reasons to do this:

You can have different nibs/storyboards for the same view/view controller. Just implement each as if you have only one nib/storyboard. Then create the view/view controller as follows:

For nib:

```
NSString *nibName = @"NAME OF ONE OF THE NIBS";
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
id view = [nibs firstObject]; // Ideally, iterate through the array and check class, then return the view.
```

For storyboard:

```
NSString *storyboardName = @"NAME OF ONE OF THE STORYBOARDS";
NSString *viewControllerIdentifier = @"VIEW CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerIdentifier];
```